# How to refer with a Foreign Key to a Primary key that has a specific value in some columns?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Let's say I have a site user table and they have an account type (client, master, and so on).

```
Create table user_info(
userId int not null,
userPassword varchar(60),
userEmail varchar(30),
userLogin varchar(25),
userType enum ('client','master','administrator'),
Constraint Pk_userId Primary Key(userId));
```

And there is a table that describes the masters, in which the identifier refers only to those identifiers in the users table that are of the master type.

```
Create table masters(
masterId int not null,
serviceId int,
Constraint Fk_masterId Foreign Key(masterId)references user_info(userId));
```

How can I do this and is it possible?

Comment: what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: You can do this in MySQL 8.0.16 using a composite key and a CHECK constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL 8.0.16 using a composite key and a CHECK constraint.

For example:

```
create table user_info (
  userId int not null,
  userPassword varchar(60),
  userEmail varchar(30),
  userLogin varchar(25),
  userType enum ('client','master','administrator') not null,
  constraint pk_userId primary key (userId),
  constraint uq1 unique (userId, userType)
);

create table masters (
  masterId int not null,
  serviceId int,
  userType enum ('client','master','administrator') not null 
    check (userType = 'master'),
  constraint fk_master foreign key (masterId, userType)
    references user_info (userId, userType)
);
```

Now, let's insert some data:

```
insert into user_info (userId, userType) values (123, 'master');

insert into masters (masterId, userType) values (123, 'master'); -- succeeds
```

But if you try:

```
insert into masters (masterId, userType) values (123, 'client'); -- fails
```

> Check constraint 'masters_chk_1' is violated.

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79aa4f1caea5040cdd328e1248079a02).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+ you can also add the user type to the referencing table and make it part of the foreign key. With a check constraint you can make sure the type is always `'master'`.

```
CREATE TABLE user_info
       (userid integer,
        usertype enum('client',
                      'master',
                      'administrator'),
        PRIMARY KEY (userid),
        UNIQUE (userid,
                usertype));

CREATE TABLE masters
             (masterid integer,
              userid integer,
              usertype enum('client',
                            'master',
                            'administrator')
                       NOT NULL
                       DEFAULT 'master',
              FOREIGN KEY (userid,
                           usertype)
                          REFERENCES user_info
                                     (userid,
                                      usertype),
              CHECK (usertype = 'master'));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13567884c5009d046ebe845652fcb3ac)

Versions prior to 8 don't enforce check constraints. You could write a trigger there that does the check.

Comment: I would only add that `usertype` must be not null.

Comment: @TheImpaler: I would hove thought that's implicitly enforced by the check constraint but indeed MySQL seems to think differently about that. So thanks for the hint! I edited the answer.

Comment: where an enum is in a foreign key, the enum labels don't need to match, just the ordinal value; so since master is the 2nd value in user_info.usertype, the enum in masters could just be ('donotuse','master') (or even ('donotuse','alwaysuse') with the default and check also being 'alwaysuse')

Comment: @stickybit Per the SQL Standard, constraints fail when their predicate evaluates to `false` only; they don't fail when they evaluate to `true` or `unknown`. A null would make the constraint evaluate to `unknown`, and that would *pass*.